# \baselineskip for 10pt, 11pt and 12pt fonts

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing, baseline

There looks like a mismatch between font height and `\baselineskip`:

```
10pt - 12.0pt (12.0pt)
11pt - 13.6pt (13.2pt)
12pt - 14.5pt (14.4pt)
```

For example, if font height is 12pt, then `\baselineskip` should be 12 * 1.2 = 14.4pt, but it is actually 14.5pt. I haven't figured out why it is defined like this. Only the value for 10pt font height is exact. I think this is why we need `\setstretch{1.213}` but not `\setstretch{1.25}` for a one-half spacing using 11pt font.

The question is, where are these `\baselineskip` values defined and why they mismatch `1.2 * font height` for 11pt and 12pt fonts?

Comment: you haven't shown any code or said what values you are looking at. in the standard classes normalsize is 10pt on 12pt large is 12pt on 14pt  but you say 14.5pt so presumably using a different class at the `[11pt]` option normalsize is 10.95pt on 13.6pt

Comment: There is no law prescribing that the baseline skip is 20% more than the font size.

Comment: oh perhaps you are using the standard classes but just looking at normalsize. normalsize with `[12pt]` option is  12pt on 14.5pt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The baselines are not calculated they are set, note also the fontsize at 11pt option is not 11pt but 10.95pt.

So looking at the standard `article` class 12pt is used for `\large` in the default `10pt` option and for `\normalsize` in the `12pt` option, but with different baselineskip. the sizes are defined for the standard classes in the files `size10.clo`, `size11.clo`, `size12.clo`

The 12pt definitions are:

**size10.clo:**

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\large{\@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{14}}
```

12pt on 14pt

**size11.clo:**

has the same definition of `\large` as the default option.

**size12.clo:**

```
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xiipt{14.5}%
```

12pt on 14.5pt

Note these are just arbitrary sizes chosen by Leslie Lamport at the beginning of time and copied with slightly modified code but the same values into LaTeX2e. There is no fixed relationship between font size and baselineskip.

Comment: I really wish people (in general,, but especially class writers) would use the baselineskip value of `\@setfontsize` rather than things like `\setstretch` to do things like double spacing. The whole baseline stretch thing was meant to be able to print a copy with extra space between lines for leaving room for proofreading marks, not to enable double spacing as mandated by theses, research papers etc. But I guess that ship has sailed.